# What is the difference between 引き渡し and 受け渡し?

Tags: word-choice

I'm having trouble understanding which one to use when, as they appear to have overlapping definitions (EDICT both have the translation "delivery").

For instance, which one do you use to describe an estate agent delivering an apartment key from the owner to a renter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are often interchangeable, but there are differences, too. 受け渡す tends to refer to a relatively casual action. 引き渡す often refers to a legally/politically important action. You may think 受け渡す is closer to "to hand" or "to communicate", and 引き渡す is closer to "to transfer (ownership, right, etc)" or "to delegate."

If you are objectively explaining how web servers and browsers work, 情報の受け渡し is probably preferred. If you are buying a secret piece of important information from a agent for a million yen, 情報の引き渡し would be preferred.

- 引き渡す is preferred: ビルの所有権を他の会社に, 亡命した政治家の身柄を政府に, 鉄道の営業権を民間会社に
- 受け渡す is preferred: ファイルを電子メールを使って, 宅配業者が荷物を受取人に, コンビニで店員がお釣りを客に

In your example, both 引き渡し and 受け渡し sound okay to me. Both the estate agent and the resident can say either 鍵の受け渡しは明日でお願いします or 鍵の引き渡しは明日でお願いします.